# Unknown column 'buyDate' in 'field list'

Tags: c#, mysql

Worked with phpMyAdmin, and wanted to update data from C#. But, I had an error:

`"Unknown column 'buyDate' in 'field list'"`

I also used string.Format for buyDate field. This is just a few parts of my code. Thanks for your help.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
        conect.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conect;

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        int result = 0;

        buyDate = string.Format("{0,10:dd/MM/yyyy}", txtBuyDate.Text);
        volume = txtVolume.Text;
        color = cboColor.SelectedValue.ToString();
        type = cboType.SelectedValue.ToString();

        cmd.CommandText = "update bucket set buyDate=@buyDate, volume=@volume, color=@color, type=@type where idBucket=@idBucket";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idBucket", idBucket);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@buyDate", buyDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@volume", volume);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color", color);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
        result += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

        if (result > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You've changed " + result + " data");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You haven't changed any data");
        }

        conect.Close();

        this.Close();
   }
```

I already know the problem. I used wrong syntax for string.Format

Answer (score 0):

Add column 'buyDate' to table 'bucket'

Or, Your date string format may have spaces.
Add quotes around your date value:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@buyDate", "'" + buyDate + "'");
```

Comment: @GraceMichelle please mark as solved if the solution worked, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer didn't solve my problem. I had an error because I used wrong syntax for string.Format. So, I ask another question to stack overflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34303634/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-phpmyadmin) (if you want to check it). But, thanks for your help