# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime phpMyAdmin

Tags: c#, datetime, phpmyadmin

Worked with phpMyAdmin, and wanted to update data from C#.

I had `"yyyy-MM-dd"` format for column `dateBuy` in phpMyAdmin.

To display it, I changed the format to `"dd/MM/yyyy"` in C#.

This is the code: (I don't have problem with this code)

```
string dateBuy = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(dateBuy);
dateBuy = time.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

To update database, I wanted to change the format back to `"yyyy-MM-dd"`. But, I had an error: `"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"`.

This is the error parts of my code:

```
string dateBuy2 = txtDateBuy.Text;
dateBuy = (DateTime.ParseExact(dateBuy2, "yyyy-MM-dd", null)).ToString();
```

Did I make mistake in the DateTime syntax? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you want to store the date in the database as a DateTime instead of a string?

Comment: When the exception is thrown, what is the content of dateBuy2 (just point the mouse on it)?

Comment: @Martheen dateBuy2 isn't too important. I can delete it, and I can move txtDateBuy.Text before "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: @jdweng Iin the database, dateBuy column is DateTime type. And, I don't know how to store date as DateTime like what you said. How can I do that?

Comment: this line `string dateBuy2 = txtDateBuy.Text;` what is the format for `txtDateBuy.Text`? dd/MM/yyyy? And what is the final format you want in dateBuy in the last line `dateBuy = (DateTime.ParseExact(dateBuy2, "yyyy-MM-dd", null)).ToString();`? yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: Uh, it's important. The exception says the string isn't formatted correctly, so you need to check the content of dateBuy2.

Comment: @GraceMichelle yes, it is as Martheen commented

Comment: @Ian for txtDateBuy.Text, user can insert with any formats they want. I want the final format in yyyy-MM-dd so it is matched with database

Comment: @Martheen hmm... Ok. But, I can't find what's wrong with that

Comment: So you want the user to insert a text in any format they want, but you use ParseExact? You need to use DateTimePicker

Comment: @Martheen i got this for exercise, and the teacher want to use textbox. So, I can't change it to DateTimePicker. And, I had tried to use parse, but it gave me another error. I use ParseExact, because I read it from another stackoverflow question

Comment: If you use TextBox, then the format used is limited in Parse (Parse use your default culture settings, or you can override them) and it's only a single format with ParseExact. Both will throw exception on invalid format, so you probably better off with TryParse. Please read [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-parse) first to get the hang of it.

Comment: What database are you using?  Normally you would add parameters to your database command.  The parameter contains a parameter System.Data.DbType. [string, int, DateTime, .....]

Answer (score 1):

[Since it is not good if we continue in the comments (the comments will be long), I will just put up what I think as a solution here]

To format `dateBuy` to the format that you want, you should also put the string format in the `ToString()`

That is, instead of

```
dateBuy = (DateTime.ParseExact(dateBuy2, "yyyy-MM-dd", null)).ToString();
```

put

```
dateBuy = (DateTime.ParseExact(dateBuy2, "yyyy-MM-dd", null)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Otherwise, it is possible for the `ToString()` to produce something like "2015-10-16 12:00:00 AM" instead of "2015-10-16"

However, since you use `ParseExact`, the input for the `dateBuy2` must also be in the format of "yyyy-MM-dd" which defeats the purpose. You may consider using `DateTimePicker` such that you can control the input format.

Alternatively, you can use `DateTime.Parse` or `TryParse` (as suggested by Martheen) instead, something like this

```
try {
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(txtDateBuy.Text);
    dateBuy = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
} catch (Exception exc) {
    //wrong format, do something to tell the user
}
```

If input has to be in the `TextBox` you better put `try-catch` to prevent your program crash for taking wrong-formatted input if you use `Parse`.

Where as if you use `TryParse`you can put it in `if-else` block statement instead

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse(txtDateBuy.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out dt)) {
    //correct format, do something using dt
} else {
    //incorrect format, warns the user
}
```

To get `CultureInfo` `enum` you need to add reference to `System.Globalization`

[Edited after suggestion given by Mr. Soner Gonul]

Comment: I suggest to use a _specific_ `IFormatProvider` instead of `null` since it uses OP's `CurrentCulture` - it _might_ use a different `Calendar` than Gregorian - result _can_ be different from what OP expected. Use `InvariantCulture` for example.

Comment: I use try-catch like what you said. I don't have this error anymore: `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`. But, either I insert the right format or wrong format, it shows the msgBox that I make: `Wrong format`. But, thank you for your help